# Azure WebJob vNet integration

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I can't get vNet integration between an Azure App Service / WebJob and it's connected Storage Account to work correctly. I have added both the App Service and the storage account to the same vNet and enabled service endpoint binding for Microsoft.Storage. From what I can see in the docs, this is what is needed to get the communication to work between the services.  Unfortunately, I get this error in the WebJob log when I try to run it:

> "Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException:
>   The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. --->
>   **System.Net.WebException**: The remote server returned an error: (403)
>   Forbidden."

If I disable the firewall on the storage account everything works just fine.

All the services are placed in the same resource group and region (West Europe).

I have tried both the "normal" (with gateway) and the new (Preview) vNet integration version on the App Service and both are failing the same way.

I am not using ASE (App Service Environment).

I have also added the following exceptions on the storage firewall:

[Storage firewall exceptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qTNo.png)

Comment: Are you using ASE and have you whitelisted your app service IP on Storage firewall?

Comment: I'm not using ASE.

Comment: And I have not whitelisted any IP in the storage firewall. The both services are in the same vNet and the Microsoft.Storage endpoint is enabled. It should be enough according to docs.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you allow the set of [trusted Microsoft services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#trusted-microsoft-services) to bypass the network rules. These services will then use strong authentication to access the storage account.
In this case, you may think **Microsoft.Networking** service will be allowed in firewall rule. But basically, [VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) does not mean App Service is inside a VNet. VNet Integration gives your web app access to resources in your virtual network but doesn't grant private access to your web app from the virtual network. We usually used to securely access the resource in a VNet.

If you want to put your App Service in a VNet, you need to deploy it in [App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro), then it's already in a VNet.

Alternatively, you could whitelist the [outbound web app service IP address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#find-outbound-ips) in the firewall rule of the storage account.

Hope this helps, feel free to let me know if you have any concerns.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the support. But it doesn't help to whitelist the outbound addresses. Because when the app service and the storage account is in the same datacenter, the app service is communication with the storage account using a private IP that can't be whitelisted. Stupid but true :-(

Comment: Why `the app service is communication with the storage account using a private IP`? Resources in the same VNet will use private Ip address but web app service and storage account do not. Have you tried to whitelist the IP in the firewall of the storage account?

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled myself on this topic.

First off, if you're restricting access to storage using the firewall you need to add your VNET to the storage firewall. Use your delegate subnet when adding your VNET.

When you add the private link between your storage and your VNET, Azure creates a private DNS zone but your app doesn't automatically use it, even when integrated to the VNET.

You can find more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet
But specifically this passage applies:

*After your app integrates with your VNet, it uses the same DNS server that your VNet is configured with. By default, your app won't work with Azure DNS private zones. To work with Azure DNS private zones, you need to add the following app settings:
WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER with value 168.63.129.16
WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL with value 1
These settings send all of your outbound calls from your app into your VNet and enable your app to access an Azure DNS private zone. With these settings, your app can use Azure DNS by querying the DNS private zone at the worker level.*

You can test the DNS resolution your app is using by opening the debug console and using the NameResolver command
NameResolver mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net or
NameResolver mystorageaccount.queue.core.windows.net
should return your private address.  If not you have a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know everyone's situation is different, but one thing that can cause this issue is Queues.

If you're mostly used to using Blob storage, you may have created the Private Endpoint on the Blob/Container (and the Vnet Integration for the WebApp) but the Webjobs need access to the Queues part of the storage too, so you need to create an additional Private Endpoint for the Queues too.

(The Kudu logs will actually specifically mention "queue" somewhere if this is the case, but they're long logs and it isn't obvious.)

(If the webjob uses Tables or File Shares, these will also need a PE each.)